# Why is khubd process using too much of my CPU?

Tags: xfce, cpu, process, debian, cpu-load

analyzing the process manager I found that the **khubd** process uses more CPU than other processes all that are running. It uses at least 25% and even uses around 40%.

Does anyone know what this process does, why it is using so much CPU and how to make it less CPU-intensive?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

khubd is a kernel thread and part of the Linux kernel USB core. khubd monitors the USB hub and will configure USB devices when they are hot-plugged into the machine.

I suspect that it is getting a lot of spurious USB hot plug events, so double check any USB devices that are plugged into your machine.